# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'from_header'

Tags: string, object, attributes, attributeerror

I am new to python. Looks like many people are facing a similar type of error. Solutions to other people's related errors don't solve my error. Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?
Thank you.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'from_header'
Here's the error report:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./../bin/make_json.py", line 169, in 
    (headerList, headers) = readHeaders(args.hdr_file)
  File "/home3/grad3/kpatel3/new_parser-gen/lib/python/HeaderLib.py", line 445, in readHeaders
    from_fields = item.next_header.mapping.from_header.asList()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'from_header'
make: *** [../examples/headers-datacenter.json] Error 1
*
Here is my piece of code:

```
class HeaderInfo:
    """Simple class for returning header info"""
    def __init__(self, length, lenIsVar, matchBytes, match):
        self.length = length
        self.lenIsVar = lenIsVar
        self.matchBytes = matchBytes
        self.match = match

class HeaderInfoAll:
    """Simple class for returning header info for all length/match combos"""
    def __init__(self, lenIsVar, lenBytes, lenMatch, lengths, nxtHdrBytes, nxtHdrMatch, nxtHdrs, defNxtHdrVal):
        self.lenIsVar = lenIsVar
        self.lenBytes = lenBytes
        self.lenMatch = lenMatch
        self.lengths = lengths
        self.nxtHdrBytes = nxtHdrBytes
        self.nxtHdrMatch = nxtHdrMatch
        self.nxtHdrs = nxtHdrs
        self.defNxtHdrVal = defNxtHdrVal

hdrLengths = {}
def readHeaders(filename):
    """Read all of the headers from a file"""

    fh = open(filename)
    data = fh.read()
    fh.close()
    parser = getHeaderBNF()
    intRE = re.compile(r'^\d+$')
    opRE = re.compile(r'^[+\-*]|<<|>>$')

    refCounts = {}
    headerList = []
    headers = {}
    for item in parser.parseString(data, True):

        if item.hdr not in headers:
            hdr = Header(item.hdr)
            headerList.append(hdr)
            headers[item.hdr] = hdr
            if item.fields != '':
                for fieldData in item.fields:
                    (name, width) = fieldData[0:2]
                    if width == '*':
                        width = None
                    else:
                        width = int(width)
                    hdr.addField(name, width)
                    if len(fieldData) == 3:
                        hdr.addExtractField(name)
            if item.next_header != '':
                if item.next_header.field != '':
                    hdr.setNextHeader(str(item.next_header.field))
                else:

                    from_fields = item.next_header.mapping.from_header.asList()
```

Can anyone help?